# Fancybox?!? + flashzoom + preview next image in the gallery

Tags: jquery, flash, fancybox, photo-gallery

I'm trying to understand how the gallery of [this website](http://www.3suisses.fr/FrontOfficePortail/catalogue_fra/linge-de-maison/bonnes-affaires/toutes-les-bonnes-affaires/taie-doreiller-carree-et-taie-de-traversin-en-polycoton-broderie/28249-taie-doreiller-carree-et-taie-de-traversin-en-polycoton-broderie.html) is implemented.

It's awesome (except for the use of flash). Studying the code I found some concern to fancybox and to a an swf file that is called when start fancybox. Passing some flashvar to this swf the zoom is generated.

Anyone have ever seen something like that? I'm unable to find any flash component or something like To avoid writing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It's been written in Flash to emulate the design of Fancybox. I don't think it actually uses any Jquery.